# I want to save events or logs grabbed using Inotify to a file

Tags: linux, bash, logging, unix-shell, inotify

I need your help - using Inotify I am watching a directory for the changes like create, delete, rename and move. I want these event to be logged in a file and I want to run Inotify as a service.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `incron` package. Then, adding new events to be monitored can be done using

```
incrontab -e
```

You can add a line to monitor specific directory. The general format is like:

```
<path> <mask> <command>
```

Directory path should be specified first, followed by event mask, and finally the command/script you want to execute. You can read `man 5 incrontab` for available masks and more info.

In your case, you can create a script to log the relevant events.